# How can i change the content of a section if my scenario variable has nothing to return?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have the above variable which displays property list based on the scenario that is active/selected. My use case is to display it as "no scenario" or something user friendly when there is no scenario available. Since this is object backed scenario variable, I am not able to customise anything.

[image]

Any advice would be great help!

[edit1]  I was thinking of some approaches to set a default scenario to which the variable can fallback to if there is no specified scenario. But since the data is being picked from the 'Load data from scenario' this is tricky. technically the Backing data source doesn't have any data in itself, its just used for structural purposes.

Any advice would be great help!

Comment: The way I have done it in the past is to basically create a variable that checks if I have a scenario selected then use a Conditional Callout Widget to display a message that no scenario is selected

Comment: if you could elaborate on conditional callout widget..

Comment: So the property you are displaying is on the scenario object or another object?

Comment: on the scenario object, so its like i have a promoted scenario, if i dont have any promoted scenarios, i need to display default metrics else i will display metrics based on that scenario, this is my usecase

Comment: i did try conditional call out widget, but it doesnt look that elegant, it just gives it like a block of text and i m not able to completely hide that section which has the other scenario linked metrics as well

Comment: I see, if you create a string variable that is defined by a variable transformation you could define some if/else logic that says display a default value if undefined

Comment: Conditional callout widget is deprecated so its not a good practice to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how i solved this was, i created two seperate sections and created 2 variables based on a variable 'X'. so if X is empty display one section (collapse the other) And vice versa. I didnt give any section header and this helped solved a lot of things. Thanks